# Receiving Errors After Upgrade to Xcode 8.2

Tags: xcode

After upgrading from Xcode 8.1 to 8.2 my project began receiving three errors that I'm unable to resolve.

When I first brought up the project in 8.2, Xcode insisted on converting to Swift 3.0, even though my project had already been converted to Swift 3.0 when I began using 8.1.  The "Use Legacy Swift Language Version" had already been set to "No".  This automatic conversion done by 8.2 did not result in any actual changes.

One error is for the <projectname>Tests.swift file, which was generated by Xcode.  Xcode 8.2 is giving a "No such module" error for the line "@testable import <projectname>".

Another error is "Command /usr/bin/ditto failed with exit code 1", but I think that's because the source file is missing that it expects to find in Xcode's derived data directory.

And another error is a "Check dependencies" error that provides the message:

> "Use Legacy Swift Language Version” (SWIFT_VERSION) is required to be configured correctly for targets which use Swift. Use the [Edit > Convert > To Current Swift Syntax…] menu to choose a Swift version or use the Build Settings editor to configure the build setting directly."

But it's already configured correctly, and the conversion has already been done.

I reinstalled 8.1 thinking it would solve the problem, but even a fresh checkout in a new directory received the same errors.  I now have both 8.1 and 8.2 installed.

Comment: this post may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41157874/use-legacy-swift-language-version-swift-version-is-required-to-be-configured/41158779

Comment: According to tom's answer, you just need to edit the `project.pbxproj` file to replace `SWIFT_VERSION = 3.0.1` with `SWIFT_VERSION = 3.0`. and all works fine...

Comment: Editing project.pbxproj followed by a Clean did the trick.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in Xcode 8.2.  Had a working project and simple flipped the targets Swift Language from "No" to "Yes" and back to "No".  The easiest way I found was to check all targets by searching for "Swift Language" in the build settings window .
Radar filed : 29756976